# angular2 tutorial , style guide for const variable

Tags: angular

Accord Style guide angular2, tells: "Consider spelling const variables in lower camel case." "The tradition of naming constants in UPPER_SNAKE_CASE reflects an era before the modern IDEs that quickly reveal the const declaration. TypeScript itself prevents accidental reassignment"

https://angular.io/styleguide#!#03-02

but in angular2 tutorial use for app.component.ts file (hero array), use  UPPER_SNAKE_CASE

```
    import { Hero } from './hero';
    export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
        {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
        {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
        {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'},
        {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'},
        {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'},
        {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'},
        {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'},
        {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'},
        {id: 19, name: 'Magma'},
        {id: 20, name: 'Tornado'}
    ];
```

why?

Comment: Most likely because the tutorial was written before the style guide.

Comment: ok; tutorial was rewritten with every new angular version, so I see they dont change the tutorial with the style guide, it's ok, thanks

Comment: I think UPPER_SNAKE_CASE is still common in Angular code. The style guide is quite new. I guess they would rather switch all UPPER_SNAKE_CASE to lowerCamelCase at once to not have inconsistencies (part of the code that way and other parts the other way). As long as this is common in Angular2 code it will come up in other parts (docs tutorials) as well. I guess a bug report in the https://github.com/angular/angular.io repo would be approriate.

Comment: I've reported the bug on github, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Imho there's a difference between naming a const containing a literal / a structure of literals or a const coming from variables:

I'd UPPER_SNAKE_CASE this:

```
const API_URL = "http://www.example.com";
```

And lowerCamelCase this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const maxHeightOfVehicle = bridges[i].height - 10;

  console.log(maxHeightOfVehicle);
}
```

Although `maxHeightOfVehicle` is technically a constant, it doesn't mean that it won't have different values over time.

`API_URL` on the other hand is a literal making it a "real constant";

So although it's not needed anymore to prevent you from changing a constant, it still tells you something about what you're dealing with.

So in the tour of heroes case I'd prefer keeping `HEROES` in UPPERCASE because it's a structure of literals. a well-defined constant.